# Вопрос по поводу очередей в RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Здравствуйте. Я пытаюсь написать очередь на rabbitmq.
На всех туториалах которых я смотрел, все работает следующим образом:

1. Есть код (отправитель), который посылает сообщение в очередь Rabbit'a и сразу завершается.
2. Есть код (получатель), который работает постоянно слушая очередь, чтобы забрать с нее сообщение.
   После того того как ОН получит сообщение из очереди, есть возможность дать сообщение rabbit'у , что он его получил. И тогда rabbit удалит его из очереди. При этом сам получатель не знает доставлено ли сообщение или нет (оно просто удалилось из очереди).

Но мне этого не достаточно. Мне нужно, чтобы отправитель узнал, что сообщение доставлено.

То есть, попытаюсь привести пример.

Отправитель кладет в очередь два сообщения:

1. "привет"
2. "пока"

Получатель получил сообщения, и отвечает :

1. "привет ок"
2. "пока не ок"

Подскажите, можно это реализовать как-то?

Comment: Вы хотите получать ответ в синхронном режиме? Или подразумевается просто уведомление по истечению времени? Если в синхронном(т.е. отправил и ждешь ответ) - то зачем вам JMS? Если в асинхронном - отсылайте с получателя сообщение куда вам требуется(будь то сервис, почта или ещё что-то). И да, если сообщение не получено, то как же вы поймете об этом?)

Comment: По факту вы лишь можете отсылать ПОСЛЕ получения сообщения что либо. Если вы ничего не получили, то это может быть как вариант того, что сообщение "потерялось" либо его не отправляли вообще

Comment: Странный вопрос. Вам достаточно узнать, что сообщение поставлено в очередь RabbitMQ. На той стороне может быть ни одного слушателя/консьюмера, либо несколько слушателей (Вы же понимаете, что RabbitMQ --очень хорош именно как БАЛАНСИРОВЩИК заданий между НЕСКОЛЬКИМИ  слушателями/обработчиками заданий, один - это лишь частный случай). Как вы собираетесь обрабатывать эти ситуации? Перечитайте фразу @Chybatiy "если сообщение не получено, то как же вы поймете об этом" и вдумайтесь.

Comment: Нет, хотелось бы, класть сообщения в очередь для получателя. 
А получатель чтобы получив и обработав сообщение клал ответ в некую "обратную" очередь, которая бы доходила до отправителя.

Comment: 1 сообщение может не быть получено, тогда оно останется в очереди.
2 сообщение может быть получено (тогджа оно пропадет с очереди ), но обработано с ошибкой.
Тому кто отправлял сообщение необходимо об этом узнать.

Comment: Вы начинали вопрос с одного ("узнать, что сообщение доставлено"), а теперь говорите о том, что вам некритично узнать, доставлено оно или нет -- фактически вы говорите о том, что у вас есть статус обработки ("обработано успешно", "обработано с ошибкой"). Давайте определимся с вопросом, что нужно-то в итоге.

Comment: Я не совсем точно выразил вопрос. нужно отправить сообщение в очередь.
1 если оно не принято, то оно продолжает лежать в очереди, до тех пор пока его не примут. 
2 если оно принято, то оно обрабатывается "приемником"  и нужно,  вернуть статус тому, кто отправлял  : успешно или нет

Comment: В случае ошибки "некорректные входные данные в задании" нужно задание удалить из очереди и больше не пытаться выполнить. Ну, возможно, сделать какую-либо нотификацию по почте/в отдельную очередь. А в случае если "пропал коннект с базой и я не не могу сейчас выполнить задание" то можно не забирать сообщение из очереди, пусть там болтается, пока не обработается до конца. Прочитайте раздел "подтверждение сообщений" (ack) ну например тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/150134/

Comment: так, давайте более приближенный пример к реальности.
 Есть отправитель на компе А, со своей БД. Мы берем строки из БД, со статусом "0" , что означает что они подлежат отправке, кладем их в rabbitmq, ставим им статус "1", что значит, что они в очереди.

 Есть получатель на компе "Б" со своей БД.  Он получает сообщение из очереди, успешно записывает в свою БД, отсылает ответ ОК.

Отправитель получает сообщение "ОК" от получателя , и ставит строкам статус "2" , что означает, что строки отправлены и записана в базу приемника.

Comment: В такой формулировке вам достаточно оперировать 'ack' (подтверждениями). И хочу вам заметить, что у вас по факту ДВЕ ОЧЕРЕДИ: одна материализована в таблице SQL-сервера, другая - в RabbitMQ. Возможно, следует задуматься о том, чтобы оставить только одну очередь.

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, то 'ack'  это подтверждение rabbit'у, чтобы он удалил задачу из очереди. Передатчик же ничего не знает об этом, он отработал, отправил сообщение и закрылся, он не слушает ответ.

Comment: Да, но вам и не нужно это. Это другая идеология, это очередь, а не коллбэки скажем. Мы вам два решения предлагаем, оба в идеологии очередей, а по сути они оба --  всё об одном и том же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно понять идеологию очередей, как они работают и в первую очередь -- "подтверждение сообщений" (acknowledgement, ack) как описано в [этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150134/).

При выполнении задания - отправлять в другую очередь "задание id=123 выполнено" после успешного выполнения задания.

Плюс опционально:

1. держать очередь для нотификаций об ошибках
2. периодически проверять "задания, которые зависли более чем на Х минут".

И ещё раз не могу не обратить ваше внимание на то, что у вас ДВЕ очереди сообщений: одна в RabbitMQ, другая - в MSSQL.

Синтетический пример. Допустим, у вас архив страничек в базе MSSQL. И тут же вы добавляете табличку, в которой ставите задания для ботов, которые качают новые статьи. Скачал - добавил новую запись в базу.

Вы сделали избыточную структуру. Можно было обойтись базой в MSSQL и хранить задания ТОЛЬКО в RabbitMQ. И держать сто подписчиков, добавлять и удалять их, чтобы качать быстрее. Обработчик взял задание, обработал, сохранил в базу, пошёл за следующим заданием. Взял другое, ан видит - статья пять минут назад обновлялась, это меньше чем заданный интервал свежести -- удалил из очереди.

Можно было бы не привлекать Rabbit MQ, оставить всё на базе MSSQL.

А у вас две очереди по факту. Такое ну бывает иногда приходится делать, если у вас MSSQL - в одной организации, а Rabbit MQ - это сторонний сервис. Или разные отделы, которые используют разные техологии (одни Linux, другие Windows), бывает и так. Но поскольку я не знаю ваших особенностей -- то просто указываю на излишнее дублировани, вероятно оно вам самому в глаза не бросается.

Comment: Я читал эту статью, приемник получает данные из очереди, ставит подтверждение, данные удаляются из очереди.  Передатчику как узнать об этом?

Comment: "Из другой очереди". Дополнил ответ, убрал лишнюю копипасту, раз вы читали эту статью.

Comment: А на уровне самого раббита нельзя такое реализовать?, Чтобы не создавать две очереди самому? Что-то очень похожее , есть в 6ом случае использования раббита
https://habrahabr.ru/post/236221/
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html

Comment: @fantastic Да, можно, но у нас в компании такой способ не прижился, поэтому именно у меня именно такого опыта нет - говорю чисто теоретически.

Answer (score 2):

Вот два варианта вам:

1. На отправителе поднимите слушатель(получатель) который будет слушать очередь B. Т.е. вы отправляете в очередь A, её обрабатывает получатель A и после отработки шлет в очередь B, которую слушает(обрабатывает) получатель B
2. Введите в сообщение какой-нибудь идентификатор. После обработки ложите данный идентификатор какое нибудь хранилище(БД к примеру) со статусом обработки. Тем самым отправитель по повторному запросу сможет получить данные из данного хранилища по идентификатору указанному в сообщении

Comment: ложите -> кладёте

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно реализовать "Удаленный вызов процедур" (RPC) через Rabbit.

Подробно на https://habr.com/ru/post/236221/

Если вкратце, то нужно написать код который посылает сообщение и сразу начинает слушать очередь ответа (Callback Queue) на наличие нужного сообщения. Как можно понять, что сообщение действительно нужное? Внутрь письма записывается CorrelationId, guid сгенерированный отправителем. Получатель не меняет этот guid и пересылает его дальше в ответе.